# HTML5 canvas saving image on tablet doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

So I'm working on a HTML5 drawing app using canvas and am using `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` to save the image.

It works perfectly fine on Desktop but on Ipad it won't work at all.

It seems like the Ipad is taking more time to render the Data-URL and trying to render the image before the url is finished.

Every time I try on Ipad it shows a blank white screen but if i hit render a few times SOMETIMES it will show the drawing. Is their any way I can asynchronously set the source of the image once the canvas is done render the Data-URL?

live example:
http://imstillreallybored.com/curtainapp/

Comment: `code` is for code, not random words!

Comment: What's the code you're using right now? `canvas.toDataURL("image/png") is not sufficient enough to detect the problem

Comment: Got this resolved Android 2.3 doesn't support Data-URIs